# Excel: simple macro to paste as text returns error 1004: Could not run the paste method of worksheet class

Tags: excel, vba

When I try to copy any text from another application to a cell in Excel 2010 (Win 7 64bits) using this macro:

```
ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Format:="Text", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False
```

I get this error:
*Error 1004 Could not run the paste method of worksheet class*

Looks like that line works fine for everybody else and some similar questions over here but none of the answers works for me

Any idea? Thanks

Comment: Why happens when you try to manually paste it?

Comment: It Works fine, but copy the content with HTML codes, special chars, links... and I only want to copy clean text. I want the same text from Copy Special option with the option Text selected, but automatic, not manually

Comment: Sorry, I should have qualified the question - Why happens when you try to manually PasteSpecial it?

Comment: PasteSpecial works fine, asks for format and copy the content in the selected Text format.

Comment: Are you using English version of Excel or Spanish one? how do you write 'Text' in Spanish?? Try to change `Format:="Text"` into `Format:="Spanish word for text here"`

Comment: Thanks a lot @KazJaw, using "Texto" solved it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Format` parameter for `.PasteSpecial` method seems to be sensitive to application national/language settings.
If you run English version of Excel than you would call this method this way (as in your question):

```
ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Format:="Text", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False
```

I'm running Polish version of Excel and the line above gives me Error 1004. But changing 'Text' into Polish 'Tekst' solve this problem:

```
ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Format:="Tekst", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False
```

If any of you doesn't know how to solve similar problem best option is to record (with macro recorder) this simple `Paste Special` operation.

Answer (score 0):

If you want [PasteSpecial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.pastespecial) to work in all languages, you can use the index of the format instead of its name:

```
ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Format:=2, Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False
```

This is if "Text" is the third paste option (index 2):
[image: Paste special formats]